# Keeping trailing zeros and numeric type

Tags: r, formatting, rounding

I would like to add two zeroes as padding to numbers and keep them as type numeric.

For example, turning 1 into 1.00.

I have seen solutions for adding two zeroes at the end of a number, but they are turned into strings.

I would like to then write those padded numbers to a text file, so if I don't keep them as numeric, they will be written with double quotation marks.

Comment: Please use more examples as it is not clear

Comment: You can fix this at the write-to-file step. For example, if you're using `write.table`, the argument you need is `quote = FALSE`

Comment: If you use another program to read the file you create with `write.table`, the trailing zeros may be removed by that program.